# Leiningen unable to run

Tags: macos, clojure, leiningen

Just installed leiningen on my mac via homebrew, and whenever I try and use it I get the following: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V

Every post to fix this I seem to come across involves the use of lein... which I can't run. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

leiningen maintains it's own upgrade task and it's faster, and easier to install it by downloading one file than to use homebrew, you also get the latest version.

- just download leiningen instead of using homebrew
- keep it up to date by running `lein upgrade`

Comment: the install script seemed to run fine but I get a no command error when trying to run 'lein'. I do see the standalone .jar in ~/lein. how do I use that?

Comment: So it sounds like you're saying it in fact didn't run fine. I'd recommend taking Arthur's advice and junking homebrew in favor of the trivially-easy [lein installer](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: no that's what I said, I downloaded the lein installer and ran it, and it seemed to run fine, there weren't any errors or anything and I saw the lein --help output after it finished, as well as seeing the new .jar in ~/lein, but the lein command itself didn't get added to the PATH or something. where does it install to exactly?